# ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'getr' with no type [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class circle
{
public:
    int r;
    getr()
    {
        cout<<"enter radius";
        cin>>r;
    }
    area()
    {
        cout<<"area is "<<(3.14*r*r);
    }
}

int main()
{
    circle one;
    one.getr();
    one.area();
    return 0;
}
```

Im getting the following errors:

> g++ /tmp/E854sHhnHj.cpp
> /tmp/E854sHhnHj.cpp:8:10: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'getr' with no type [-fpermissive]
> 8 |     getr()
> |          ^

> /tmp/E854sHhnHj.cpp:13:10: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'area' with no type [-fpermissive]
> 13 |     area()
> |          ^

> /tmp/E854sHhnHj.cpp:17:2: error: expected ';' after class definition
> 17 | }
> |  ^
> |  ;
> /tmp/E854sHhnHj.cpp: In member function 'int circle::getr()':

> /tmp/E854sHhnHj.cpp:12:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
> 12 |     }
> |     ^

> /tmp/E854sHhnHj.cpp: In member function 'int circle::area()':
> /tmp/E854sHhnHj.cpp:16:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
> 16 |     }
> |     ^

Comment: If you don't want to return something, you need to declare it: `void getr()`

Comment: and put ';' after your class definition

Comment: What C++ book are you reading?

Comment: I am asking because there is a lot of junk C++ books out there, and we need to warn people against using them. You may benefit from a [good one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to state the return types in your member function definitions:

```
void getr() { ... }
^^^^
```

Comment: i want it to ask for a radius and print the area... the void gives me a result like: 
$g++ -o main *.cpp
$main
enter radiusarea is 0

Answer (score 4):

All functions in C++ (whether they are members of classes or free-standing) need a declared return type (before the function name). In your case, as the functions aren't returning anything, you should declare those return types as `void`.

Also, you're missing a semicolon after the class definition:

```cpp
class circle {
public:
    int r;
    void getr() { // Need a return type for functions - "void" seems logical here
        cout << "enter radius";
        cin >> r;
    }
    void area() { // ... and again
        cout << "area is " << (3.14 * r * r);
    }
}; // Must have a semicolon here!
```

Comment: i want it to ask for a radius and print the area... the void gives me a result like: 

$g++ -o main *.cpp $main enter radiusarea is 0

Comment: @Roshan No the void does not give you anything like that. Something else does. The suggested fix [works](https://godbolt.org/z/exs5Mq5jo).

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. ohok now i see it, thanks. since u asked: im studying from my professor's notes and havent got a book as of now.